I'm trying to run openmm and mdtraj for a project. Openmm worked but mdtraj didn't work, though I used the same process
I am working on an assignment and need all these packages.
from __future__ import print_function

from openmm import app
import openmm as mm
from openmm import LocalEnergyMinimizer
from openmm import unit
import sys
import mdtraj
import mdtraj.reporters
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

I didn't have openmm or Mdtraj packages, i downloaded both in bash and within my conda environment just to make sure they work.
But when i run my code i get this error.
water2.py", line 8, in <module>
    import mdtraj
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mdtraj'

mdtraj didn't work, so i checked the file.
pip show mdtraj

Name: mdtraj
Version: 1.10.1
Summary: MDTraj: A modern, open library for the analysis of molecular dynamics trajectories
Home-page: http://mdtraj.org
Author: Robert McGibbon
Author-email: rmcgibbo@gmail.com
License: LGPLv2.1+
Location: C:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, packaging, pyparsing, scipy
Required-by: 

then I tried reinstalling it.
conda install -c conda-forge mdtraj --force-reinstall
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: | 

after running the program, it stops here and stalls for long.
What am I doing wrong?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you using the same python interpreter that is associated to the same conda environment you're installing the packages to?
